# How to paste commands into vim command mode?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

It used to be possible to leave vim in *command mode* (rather than *insert mode*) and then paste some copied characters into the vim window to make it execute the characters as a sequence of commands. So you could copy `n0dt@` and when you pasted it in, it would search for the next item you last searched for (`n`), go to the beginning of that line (`0`), and delete everything up to the first `@` character in that line (`dt@`). Then you could paste it again and it would do it again on the next item, etc.

Now when I paste into the vim window, it somehow detects that I'm pasting rather than typing, and it "helpfully" switches into insert mode and just inserts the literal characters `n0dt@`, which isn't what I want. Is this a recent change to vim (like within the last couple of years)? Is there a way to turn off this automatic switch to insert mode on paste? (In case it's relevant, I'm running vim in Cygwin, pasting into a mintty window with a right-click.)

Comment: I've only been using vim for 2 years, so I don't know if this is a recent change, but I've always used the 'normal' command (i.e. type 'normal', or just 'norm' in command-line mode), followed by the sequence of things I want vim to do (as if I typed them into vim while in normal mode). :normal n0dt@

Comment: The behaviour you describe is the expected behaviour of Shift+Insert.

Comment: Neither of those is what I want. I want to execute the commands *by pasting them*, without typing anything. Typing ":normal n0dt@" is more typing than simply typing "n0dt@". I want to execute the commands represented by "n0dt@" without touching the keyboard at all, by clicking the right mouse button once, to paste the characters "n0dt@" into command mode (not command-line mode). Shift+Insert just inserts the characters as text, just like pasting does currently.

Comment: Clicking the right mouse button *does* Shift+Insert in your terminal emulator. If you don't want that, configure your terminal emulator to do something else.

Comment: Well, romainl, the terminal says the action of the right mouse button is "paste" (as opposed to "extend", "menu", or "enter"). Is there a way to change vim's settings so that the action of Shift+Insert (or paste) is to execute the characters as commands? I know it used to do that by default (as long as vim was in command mode when I did the paste) because I have many times created a command sequence, copied it, and repeatedly pasted it in to execute it.

Comment: @Neo, to make sure I really understood your issue I pulled an old version of Vim at random (7.4.909) and I can now confirm that it behaved the way you want while the default Vim on my system (8.0.1365) and the one I actually use (8.2.2681) both insert the macro instead of executing it, all with the same options. I see there have been lots of patches related to pasting starting from 8.0, which may or may not have introduced that change. For the record, this is not on Windows and not in Cygwin so the issue is definitely in Vim itself, regardless of platform/terminal emulator/shell.

Comment: Thanks, romainl! I wonder if they considered this change to be like a bug fix, so they didn't provide a way to revert to the old behavior (which I found really useful)? Is there some option now or some other workaround to allow commands to be pasted in? Is there a forum for vim developers that would be a better place to ask these questions?

Comment: I haven't pinpointed the exact moment and the exact change so I am unable to provide a solution or workaround and I don't plan to dig much further. [The official issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) is your best chance.

Comment: Thanks so much, romainl. Your confirming that it's an issue in vim and pointing me to the issue tracker were really helpful!

Comment: Turns out it's called bracketed paste. To revert to the old behavior, do ":set t_BE=".

Comment: @Neo, you should post an answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's called *bracketed paste*. To revert to the old behavior, use

```
:set t_BE=
```